# fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: You

Tags: git

I'm on Ubuntu. I didn't have any issues with git but out of the blue I start seeing this error for any remote git operations like git pull, push etc.
Searched the other posts on this and when I ran
ssh git@hostname git-upload-pack '/path_to_your_repo'

I got-" You don't have access."

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, and for me it was the case of echoing "You've got mail." in the shell. Don't know why it's so fragile about an echo, but I re-wrote my mail check to first check if it has a tty before echoing the mail.